# Conditionally log in or log out button in keycloak Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication, keycloak, keycloak-services

I would like to change the button name and function (Log In and .login() if the user isn't logged and Log Out and logout() if the user is logged).

I tried to use the function .IsLoggedIn() from KeycloakService but it doesn't work.

I also tried to use .authenticated but it doesn't work because it returns "undefined".

Here is my markup in `navbar.component.html` :

```
<li ngbNavItem="navbar-logout" style="float: right">
    <a ngbNavLink
      ><button
        *ngIf="this.authService.isLoggedIn(); else elseBlock"
        class="btn"
        id="navbar-logout"
        (click)="deconnexion()"
      >
        Log Out
      </button>
      <ng-template #elseBlock
        ><button class="btn" id="navbar-login" (click)="connexion()">
          Log In
        </button></ng-template
      >
    </a>
  </li>
```

Here is my code in `navbar.component.ts` :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css'],
})
@dvoconstrlog()
export class NavbarComponent {
  constructor(protected authService: AuthService) {}

  deconnexion() {
    this.authService.logout();
  }
  connexion() {
    this.authService.login();
  }
}
```